# Slow insert into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

[image]

[image]

What can be the reason for slow inserts into my SQL Server table compared to my local DB with 4GB of memory the script which is running less than 2 seconds while on my client's server with 1GB memory (attached image) it took 50 seconds.

Below is a sample query, records from my local and from my client's db are almost the same count.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempUnitServiceLogs') IS NOT NULL
    drop table #TempUnitServiceLogs

Select 
    F.Unit_Id, MAX(F.UnitTransaction_Id) UnitTransaction_Id 
into 
    #TempUnitServiceLogs
from 
    TempUnitServiceLogs F 
group by  F.Unit_Id



insert into TempUnitServiceLogs
    Select 
        A.Unit_Id
        ,C.Brand_Name
        ,A.Unit_CompanyCode
        ,B.Project_Code
        ,A.Unit_Code 
        ,A.Unit_Status  

    from  Table1 A
    inner join Table2 B on A.Project_Id = B.Project_Id
    inner join Table3 C on B.Brand_Id = C.Brand_Id
    left join #TempUnitServiceLogs D on A.Unit_Id = D.Unit_ID
    left join Table4 ut on ut.Unit_Id = A.Unit_Id
    left join Table5 pb on pb.ProspectiveBuyer_Id = ut.ProspectiveBuyer_Id  
    where 1=1 
      and d.UnitTransaction_Id IS NULL
      and case when UnitTransaction_ModDate IS null 
        then convert(date,UnitTransaction_CrDate) 
      else convert(date,UnitTransaction_ModDate) end = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Could be a lot of things. How big is the client's table compared to yours? Does the client's table have indexes that your table doesn't?  How much traffic is hitting the client's table? BTW, you might be better off asking this question on dba.stackechange.

Comment: How many rows are you talking about being inserted? 100, 100 K, 100 M?

Comment: Answering 'why is this slow' questions is easier if you can share the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: usually this is about less than 50 records only. #TempUnitServiceLogs holds 40K records only while Table4  holds 2M records. same index has been applied to destination table, but its applied on the column with identity just to have an unique ID.

Comment: Is that the estimated or actual execution plan that you included as a picture? It would be easier for others here to analyze if you use  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ because then we can view tooltips and don't have issues with trying to fit all the plan into view for a screen capture.

Comment: Are you saying the indexes are identical between databases or not? There are 5 tables, two selects and one insert involved here. The issue could be the select, not the insert. The only way to find out is compare all of these things. You also need to look at the server config. Maybe one is going parallel and one isn't (but the query plan will tell you). Lastly use `sp_who2` to see what is actually happening while it is running

Comment: Hi please see this link https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By9tCpCee

Comment: Yes Nick, sorry for the confusion, since the select statement is running  long, it took 50 seconds before the records inserted to the destination table. Anyway, is  it OK to have only 1GB memory if this is being used by multiple user?

Comment: Certainly I would very be surprised to see a production SQL Server with only 1G of memory. Is this the total server memory or the max memory assigned to the SQL Server? If you google "sql server memory pressure" you'll find some methods to capture solid figures to confirm you have a memory issue. Actually for 2Million records I can be pretty certain that 1G is not enough for reasonable performance. But keep in mind everything is measurable

Comment: I find it amazing that someone is running SQL Server with a machine with 1GB of RAM. But I'm not seeing any spill to disk during the hash matches like I expected.

Comment: Any production sql box with less than 4GB is asking for performance problems. I don't configure SQL prod boxes with less than 16GB. My desktop has 16GB, let alone a prod sql box!!

Comment: i already checked the problem in my client again, and found that my where clause is causing the problem. basically i would like to get the records based on Created Date Column and Modified Date Column which ever is equal to current date and insert the results to destination table,  And the issue about 1 GB is not the real issue now, it's their decision to set it as 1GB only to check that even there are many running process on the server my script will not affect and will not consume all remaining memory

Comment: If I understand correctly, 1Gb is the correct answer to this question, but it is handed off to the client. (Note that the hour I spent answering this question probably cost more than a Gig of server RAM). If you have a logic issue, I suggest you open a new question and explain in detail